# sorting data from quick.db

Tags: discord.js, quick.db

```
const db = require('quick.db')
let data = db.get(`someidhere.reviews`).sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data)
    data.length = 5;
    var final = "";
    var i = 0;
    for (i in data) {
      final += `${data[i]} \n`
    }
message.channel.send(final || "none")
```

the "reviews" returns an array everything is fine but my question is is there a possible way to get for example the 6th review after the first 5 reviews without sending all the other reviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `data[5]`.

```
const db = require('quick.db')
let data = db.get(`someidhere.reviews`).sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data);
const final = data[5] || "none";
message.channel.send(final)
```

Comment: Is there a way to get more than 1 like from 5 to 10

Comment: Yes, take a look at [Array#splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)